# What does "+\" mean? Python Building request Xml

Tags: python, xml

At the end of the each of the lines there is a "+\":

```
def buildRequestXml(detailLevel, viewAllNodes):
    requestXml = "<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>"+\
              "<AddItemRequest xmlns=\"urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents\">"+\
              "<RequesterCredentials><eBayAuthToken>" + userToken + "</eBayAuthToken></RequesterCredentials>"

    if (detailLevel != ""):
        requestXml = requestXml + "<DetailLevel>" + detailLevel + "</DetailLevel>"

    requestXml = requestXml + "<Item>"+\
                    "<BuyItNowPrice>10.0</BuyItNowPrice>"+\
                    "<Country>US</Country>"+\
                    "<Currency>USD</Currency>"+\
                    "<Description>This is a test.</Description>"+\
                    "<ListingDuration>Days_7</ListingDuration>"+\
                    "<Location>San Jose, CA</Location>"+\
                    "<PaymentMethods>PaymentSeeDescription</PaymentMethods>"+\
                    "<PrimaryCategory>"+\
                    "  <CategoryID>357</CategoryID>"+\
                    "</PrimaryCategory>"+\
                    "<Quantity>1</Quantity>"+\
                    "<StartPrice>1.0</StartPrice>"+\
                    "<ShippingTermsInDescription>True</ShippingTermsInDescription>"+\
                    "<Title>Test item title</Title>"+\
                "</Item>"+\
              "</AddItemRequest>"
    return requestXml
```

Comment: This calls for triple quotes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a line continuation operator. Basically it's escaping the invisible newline char, forcing Python to treat all that as a single line.

e.g.

```
somevar = 'foo'+\
    'bar'
```

is identical to

```
somevar = 'foo'+'bar'
```

Answer (score 2):

The `\` is a line continuation character, meaning the next line is a continuation of the current line

However, it is preferred to use parentheses to continue implicitly, per the [PEP-0008](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#maximum-line-length) style guide:

> The preferred way of wrapping long lines is by using Python's implied line continuation inside parentheses, brackets and braces. Long lines can be broken over multiple lines by wrapping expressions in parentheses. These should be used in preference to using a backslash for line continuation.

---

Using parentheses instead of `\`**:**

```
requestXml = (requestXml + "<Item>"+
    "<BuyItNowPrice>10.0</BuyItNowPrice>"+
    "<Country>US</Country>"+
    "<Currency>USD</Currency>"+
    "<Description>This is a test.</Description>"+
    "<ListingDuration>Days_7</ListingDuration>"+
    "<Location>San Jose, CA</Location>"+
    "<PaymentMethods>PaymentSeeDescription</PaymentMethods>"+
    "<PrimaryCategory>"+
    "  <CategoryID>357</CategoryID>"+
    "</PrimaryCategory>"+
    "<Quantity>1</Quantity>"+
    "<StartPrice>1.0</StartPrice>"+
    "<ShippingTermsInDescription>True</ShippingTermsInDescription>"+
    "<Title>Test item title</Title>"+
  "</Item>"+
"</AddItemRequest>")
```

By wrapping the expression in parentheses, Python knows to continue onto the next line.

Comment: Thanks for including an example of how it should look.

Answer (score 0):

\ denotes a line continuation.